# Mostrar numero en el marcador del mapa

Tags: android, mapsforge

necesito poder mostrar un numero dentro del marcador del mapa. Utilizo mapsforge en su version 0.13.0. El codigo de mi clase marcador es la siguiente:

```
public class MyMarker extends Marker {
private Context ctx;

public MyMarker(Context ctx, LatLong latLong, Bitmap bitmap, int horizontalOffset,
                int verticalOffset) {
    super(latLong, bitmap, horizontalOffset, verticalOffset);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

@Override
public boolean onTap(LatLong tapLatLong, Point layerXY, Point tapXY) {
    if (this.contains(layerXY, tapXY)) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Marker con latitud: " + tapLatLong.latitude + " y longitud: " + tapLatLong.longitude + " pulsado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTap(tapLatLong, layerXY, tapXY);
}
```

}

Comment: Marca algùn error o que simplemente no se ve? como mandas llamar esta clase MyMarker desde tu mapa?

Comment: No, lo que no se es como hacer para mostrar el numero, y la llamo de esta manera:

Comment: marker = new MyMarker(this, new LatLong(Double.parseDouble(latitud), Double.parseDouble(longitud)), AndroidGraphicFactory.convertToBitmap(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_icon_posicion)), 0, 0);